# Voltage gain of an Emitter Follower

Tags: emitter-follower

Please see attached image. Can you please help me understand how they went from the first to the second? Not too sure how they got (B+1) in there.

Thanks

[image: Emitter Follower]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With simple algebra, from \$(5.317)\$ you get:
$$
v_\pi=\frac{v_{out}}{R_E}\frac{r_\pi}{g_mr_\pi+1}
$$
Now:
$$
\beta\triangleq\frac{i_c}{i_b}\\
i_b=\frac{v_\pi}{r_\pi}\\
i_c=g_mv_\pi\\
\implies \beta=g_mv_\pi\frac{r_\pi}{v_\pi}=g_mr_\pi
$$
And plugging this result in the first equation you get \$(5.318)\$:
$$
v_\pi=\frac{v_{out}}{R_E}\frac{r_\pi}{\beta+1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

B=R(pi)xGm
On first line, make a common denominator on left side.
You will get: V(pi)(1+(GmxR(pi))/R(pi)
Replace R(pi)xGm with B and solve for V(pi) and you get the second equation.

Comment: Sorry I'm still not seeing it. How does B=R(pi)xGm? Also how does R(pi)/(1+B) = 1/Gm? Also how does (1+Gm.R(pi)) =B+1?

Answer (score 0):

$$I_b + I_c = I_e$$

Since:
$$\frac{I_c}{I_b} = \beta$$

Then:

$$\begin{align}
I_b + \beta(I_b) &= I_e \\\\
\Rightarrow  (\beta+1)Ib &= Ie   \tag 1
\end{align}$$

From the circuit diagram:

$$\begin{align}
I_b = \frac{v_\pi}{r_\pi} &&\text{and} &&
I_e = \frac{v_{out}}{R_E}
\end{align}$$

Substituting in (1)

$$\frac{v_{out}}{R_E} = \frac{(\beta+1)V_\pi}{r_\pi}$$

Then by re arranging the terms:

$$V_\pi = \frac{r_\pi}{(\beta+1)}\cdot\frac{v_{out}}{R_e}$$